# Can I use XPCOM to create and manipulate a Firefox window as I would use win32 COM with IE?

Tags: c++, python, xul, xpcom, browser-automation

With win32 COM I create an Internet Explorer instance and control it almost fully from my python code (manipulate windows, DOM elements, etc). More specifically, using DispatchEx('InternetExplorer.Application'). Can I do the same using XPCOM and C++/python?

I need to automate certain actions taken on the html ui of some websites, so no I can't use urllib and I can't use selenium, because it doesn't work with cross-domain urls. I've wrote a wrapper class for Internet Explore where I can create a browser window and do anything with it, but I would like to do the same with firefox as well. I've thought about creating a XUL application that exposes the DOM functionality through a tcp server written in XUL/js. I'm not even sure that's possible, but if I can do everything from my python code without running xulrunner externally, much better.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about programmatically creating and controlling full Firefox instances, but Mozilla can definitely be embedded using XPCOM.
The [Mozilla embedding FAQ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla_Embedding_FAQ/Embedding_Gecko#Can_I_embed_Mozilla_in_any_other_way.3f), [embedding how-to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Roll_your_own_browser_-_An_embedding_HowTo) and the [embedding APIs overview](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla_embedding_APIs_overview) should get you started. There are also [other means](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla_Embedding_FAQ/Embedding_Gecko#Can_I_embed_Mozilla_in_any_other_way.3f) for embedding.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the [nsIDOMXULElement](http://xulplanet.mozdev.org/references/xpcomref/nsIDOMXULElement.html) to attach event listeners in my XPCOM C++ code. I haven't tried modifying the UI, but it will probably work as well.

For an example on how to get an nsIDOMXULElement look at the call "SetVideoWindow" in Songbird's code [here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=nl#OGomNmoy7MM/trunk/client/components/mediacore/gstreamer/src/sbGStreamerMediacore.cpp).